Equirectangular projection with multiple fisheye
I am trying to extend articles I found at https://paulbourke.net/dome/dualfish2sphere/ to project multiple frames from several fisheye cameras with partial overlap and 360 total FOV (with known intrinsics & relative transformations) into a single equirectangular frame.
I am failing a lot though. I get the normalized equirectangular -> normalized fisheye conversion, I already have it implemented also in Python. However:

How to unnormalize the fisheye coordinates? Using the input image width/height does not seem enough: this is good for a single image, but does not leave enough room for over images to be projected to the same equirectangular frame.
There exactly should we take into account image center for each fisheye camera? At the final step? Or somewhere else entirely?
Finally, at which moment we get to apply rotation & translation of individual cameras so they are not all projected to same location in the output (I tried to apply it to 3D vectors from the tutorial - unsuccessfully, probably)?

